# How to keep chat history locally on android?

Tags: xmpp, smack

I am using openfire and aSmack for my chat application.

I am able to send and receive messages using aSmack library.

Can anyone tell me how to keep these messages in local(android) storage, so that whenever user opens application next time, he can see his previous chat history ? Is there any api provided by aSmack/Smack ?

Comment: well sqlite would be a good option

Comment: check this https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Local-Databases-with-SQLiteOpenHelper

Comment: Yes. I know about sqlite. But is there any api provided by aSmack just like openfire keeps group chat history ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply register a packet listener and interceptor and log the messages to the backing store of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

use packetListener as:

```
PacketFilter gc_filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.groupchat);

        XMPPconnection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() 
        {
            public void processPacket(Packet packet) 
            {
                final Message message = (Message) packet;
                String body = message.getBody();
                String from_jid = message.getFrom();
                // save it in data base
            }
        )};
```